# BMP texture doesn't show

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, textures, bmp

I've encountered a problem whilst learning how to texture in OpenGL (from OpenGL 5th Edition Bible). The problem is that I **can't display my texture**. I load it from a BMP file with a function I've written myself.

Since code is quite lengthy I uploaded all neccessery files. You can download it from [here](http://rob1n92.pl/download/opengl.tar.bz2).

EDIT: I've tried copying code from the mentioned book (TGA loading described there) and it doesn't work as well. It seems that loading stucks at loading image data from file (strange). I suppose it isn't relevant as far as my problem is concern.

Comment: Use [SDL_image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/), [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html) or similar library. You won't have to write it yourself and it will automatically support many image formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are general debug steps for checking for problems. I will list them below in the hope you might find the bug (and for future readers):

- Does the file exist? Is the file being read properly according to the format? Did you get it to gel well with OpenGL? My suggestion: Do not mess with these things yourself. Use a library. There's an amazingly light weight [SOIL (Simple OpenGL Image library)](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html)
- Are you loading the textures before initialising OpenGL? This was always my problem because I used to "load" and do a `glBindTexture(..)` in the constructor (of some class). The objects were created before OpenGL was initialised.
- Have you enabled `GL_TEXTURE_2D`? Check the initialise code, use: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`
- Did you map the textures properly with the quad or the shape you want it on? Expanding on this here is (sort of) out of scope. There are great [tutorials](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-texture-mapping-an-introduction-r947) out there.
- (Would seem stupid, but happens sometimes) Are you blacking out the object by `glColor3f(0,0,0)` ?

*<sub>There could be more checks, but these are the ones hitting my head now</sub>*

Comment: Apparently the problem was quite complex. My BMP loading and rendering function  must have been wrongly written, since swapping to SOIL and getting rid of all _glColor_ I finally managed to display the texture. Thanks for help :)